# My best friend supports lgbtq...and she is muslim, what can I tell her?

Tags: sin, punishment, homosexuality

Salam brothers and sisters, hope you are all doing well...

I have a very close friend of mine that I love and care for, she is not just my best muslim friend but my best friend of all friends, even our moms are very close.

She supports homosexuality and I tried telling her a couple of times that it's wrong and even sent her the verse from the Quran about men approaching men with lust instead of women. But she wouldn't listen...
I told her she she shouldn't support it because Prophet Lut's wife supported homosexuality and she had consequences, after I told her that she left me on seen but hearted my message.

Then recently she posted on her Instagram a chat of her messaging someone who was homophobic and saying what's wrong with being gay and captioned something like "imagine being homophobic, I could never".(Not saying muslims should be homophobic by the way, I just want her to recognize how wrong homosexuality is and that she should not support it)

So even after telling her that homosexuality is wrong and even why, she still continues to support. I don't want my friend to face horrible consequences, I want her to know what's right and wrong becuase I really care for her and we've known eachother for a long time. I don't know what I can tell her anymore...can someone please tell me what I should say? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Firstly

As someone who is bisexual, being apart of the LGBT is haram in terms of:

1. Supporting the sins they do
2. Advocating for their rights to continue their sinning
3. Publicizing your sexuality

However it is not haram in terms of:

1. Feeling attracted to the same sex as long as you don’t indulge in the haram
2. Treating them like people and with kindness

Your friend might be confused and believing that if she doesn’t support the LGBT, she’ll be considered homophobic. Which is understandable since unfortunately our society is practically forcing the acceptance of a his sin, other wise you’ll be shamed and ridiculed.
However, homophobia can be the following too:

1. Discriminating someone based off of their sexuality
2. Abusing them, slandering them

If you keep quiet about the issue, such as just saying, “I don’t support it but I respect the decision you have” and move on, then you should be fine.

Do your part in advising her, educating, and informing her.
If she still doesn’t listen, make dua for her to understand, and leave it be. Don’t continue to stress and force someone for them not to understand in the end.

I pray she understands.